# Update HTML table every 5 seconds with mySQL, and PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple PHP page that sends a query to a mySQL database and displays the data onto a HTML table.

How can I get it to do this every 5 seconds? Currently it does this upon the page loading. The database will have changing data, so am trying to get the code to refresh every 5 seconds to keep the table updated.

How might I go upon doing this?

Comment: you have to use jquery ajax for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript ajax. For example ,

```
 <script>
 function loadXMLDoc()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; // your div
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getdatabase.php",true); //your php file
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 window.setInterval(function(){
   loadXMLDoc();
 }, 5000);

 </script>
```

Then in html , you must have a div with specified ID(myDiv) Fpr example:

```
 <body>
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
 </body>
```

Then in getdatabase.php you must fetch the value from the database and echo it out. For example,

```
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>";

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Hope it works , see more at www.w3schools.com/

Comment: So the index page is in PHP. For your first block of code, would I embed that into the index page? Also why do I need a div? So I was using the third block of code on the index page as well. Does that need to be on a separate one?

Comment: First and second block is in your index page.

Comment: If the third one is on a separate page, how is it able to embed the table onto the index page?

Comment: That's called ajax trick. in javascript you'll see that there is one line saying document.getelementByID(myDiv)=xmlhttp.responseText; That means everything echo from the getdatabase.php will be send to myDiv

Comment: It loads the table and such, but I have to manually refresh the page in order for it to add a new entry?

Comment: @tyler5819 I edited my code , change while(true) loop into window.setinterval.... please try it. Sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a client-side scripting language such as JavaScript to have a webpage do something after it has been served to a client.

Specifically, you will want to use [timers](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and [AJAX calls](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp). You may also find the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library useful for abstracting AJAX calls however it is not a requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Use javascript timers. From there-on u can periodically run the SQL command to read the databases.

If this problem still arises, I can post some example code.